# Display "x results found" or "no results found" when returning MySQL Query results

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

The search function works like a charm, but I'm not sure how to add certain "extras" to it.  When there are results to display, I would also like it to say:

```
"Your search returned x results."
```

Followed by the results.

When there are no results to display, I would like it to say:

```
"Your search returned no results.  Please try again."
```

And when the user does not input anything into the search form, I would like it to say:

```
"You did not enter a search term."
```

I'm a PHP beginner, and I'm not sure how to implement this into my current code; I've tried a bunch of different ways, and it either gives me errors or returns a blank page when there are no results.

Any direction or help would be great.  Thank you.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php

//STEP 1 Connect To Database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","tarb89_admin","leccums");
if (!$connect)
{
    die("MySQL could not connect!");
}

$DB = mysql_select_db('tarb89_characters');

if(!$DB)
{
    die("MySQL could not select Database!");
}

//STEP 2 Check Valid Information
if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
    //STEP 3 Declair Variables
    $Search = $_GET['search'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name LIKE '%$Search%' ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $name        = $row['name'];
        $id          = $row['id'];
        $breed       = $row['breed'];
        $gender      = $row['gender'];
        $genetics    = $row['genetics'];
        $profile     = $row['profile'];
        $player      = $row['player'];
        $color       = $row['color'];
        $markings    = $row['markings'];
        $traits      = $row['traits'];
        $defects     = $row['defects'];
        $extras      = $row['extras'];

        echo "  <h3>$name</h3>
        <table width='700px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
        <td><p>
        <b>ID Number:  </b>$id<br>
        <b>Breed:  </b>$breed<br>
        <b>Gender:  </b>$gender<br>
        <b>Genetics: </b>$genetics<br>
        <b>Profile:</b>  <a href='$profile'>$profile</a><br>
        <b>Player:</b>  $player</p></td>
        <td><p>        
        <b>Color:</b>  $color<br>
        <b>Markings:</b>  $markings<br>
        <b>Traits:</b>  $traits<br>
        <b>Defects:</b>  $defects<br>
        <b>Extras:</b>  $extras</p></td>
        </table>";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Separate HTML from PHP, use PDO, initialize a variable with 0 and in the loop increment it then at the end if 0 message_1:No results else message_2:You have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows()` to return number of rows

```
if($search!="") {
    // Your Query

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num >= 1)
    {
        echo "Your search returned $num results";
        // your code
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your search returned no results. Please try again";
    }
} else {
    echo "You did not enter a search term";
}
```

**YOUR CODE**

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    //STEP 3 Declair Variables
    $Search = $_GET['search'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name LIKE '%$Search%' ");

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num >= 1)
    {
    echo "Your search returned $num results";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $name        = $row['name'];
        $id          = $row['id'];
        $breed       = $row['breed'];
        $gender      = $row['gender'];
        $genetics    = $row['genetics'];
        $profile     = $row['profile'];
        $player      = $row['player'];
        $color       = $row['color'];
        $markings    = $row['markings'];
        $traits      = $row['traits'];
        $defects     = $row['defects'];
        $extras      = $row['extras'];

        echo "  <h3>$name</h3>
        <table width='700px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
        <td><p>
        <b>ID Number:  </b>$id<br>
        <b>Breed:  </b>$breed<br>
        <b>Gender:  </b>$gender<br>
        <b>Genetics: </b>$genetics<br>
        <b>Profile:</b>  <a href='$profile'>$profile</a><br>
        <b>Player:</b>  $player</p></td>
        <td><p>        
        <b>Color:</b>  $color<br>
        <b>Markings:</b>  $markings<br>
        <b>Traits:</b>  $traits<br>
        <b>Defects:</b>  $defects<br>
        <b>Extras:</b>  $extras</p></td>
        </table>";
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your search returned no results. Please try again";
    }
} else {
        echo "You did not enter a search term";
}
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, Move on `mysqli_*` functions asap

Comment: Where in my current code would I place this?  Do I replace parts of it or just add it somewhere?  I'm sorry for the dumb questions.  I'm very new at this.  Thank you!

Comment: I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home3/tarb89/public_html/aususrpg.net/charbase/search.php on line 64."

Comment: When there are no results to display, it works fine.  When there is no search term it shows all the data in the database.  When you search for something that is listed in the database, it shows the "your search returned no results, please try again" message.

Comment: @user2965612 now check again

Comment: Everything except for the "You did not enter a search term" part works perfectly.  PS: Thank you so much for your help.  It is much appreciated!